# Changing the Color of an Includegraphics Basic Frame with Adjustbox

Tags: includegraphics, adjustbox, frame

MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\includegraphics[frame=2pt]{example-image-A}  
\end{document}
```

gives

[image]

I would like to change the color of the frame from black to something else, say blue. Is there a way to do this along the lines of, say, [frame,color=blue] (which of course, doesn't work)?

Note: In my actual document, I am trying to blot out a blemish on an image, which `[frame]` takes care of nicely; and so, I am hoping for as simple a solution as possible, without resorting to the creation of other types of boxes in lieu of `[frame]`.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but the book class does not have an `tikz` option.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Thanks for pointing that out; I'm surprised I didn't get an error when compiling.

Comment: You get a warning about an unused option in your .log file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a `cframe` key instead of `frame`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\includegraphics[cframe=blue 2pt]{example-image-duck}  
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answer.

Comment: @jean-marie You're welcome!

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to load Ti*k*Z (`book` class dosen't admit `tikz` as an option, you need to load it with `\usepackage`), so here is an option:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw=blue,line width=2pt,inner sep=0] {\includegraphics{example-image}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. This see,s to work nicely for `standalone` class, but it doesn't for `book` class, which is the class my original document is in.

Comment: @jean-marie You need to load the `tikz` package if you use the book class. (not as a class option, but with the normal `\usepackage{...}`)

Comment: Also, when I add `\usepackage{tikz}`, a blue frame appears, but not as nice as the one in `standalone`.

Comment: @jean-marie, I see no difference

Comment: +1 Thank you; perhaps the problem is on my end.